# Cell animations with IGListKit

Tags: objective-c, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using IGListKit and want to have custom animations when inserting cells.

Normally I would subclass a UICollectionFlowLayout and override

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and return all of the attributes needed for the animation.

However, when doing this with IGListKit I am getting a weird behaviour where all of the cells animate, not just the cells that are being inserted. How can this be done with IGListKit?

Comment: Can you provide a sample app for this? Also, opening an issue on Github might be a bit quicker https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/issues/new

Comment: That is how IGListKit seems to work. From my experience with this framework, seems from the source code that all the cells are deleted and re-inserted for every update.